# Spellchecker in eclipse doesn't recognize certain strings

Tags: eclipse, spell-checking

Spellchecker in eclipse doesn't recognize certain strings like `'finalize', 'randomize'` even though they are correct. Is there a setting which needs to be enabled so that these don't show up as issues in the Eclipse java file editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the strings to a user defined dictionary. Check out the General > Editors > Text Editors > Spelling page on the Preferences dialog (found under Window > Preferences).